# How many nodes are there in an empty binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I got this question when I worked on a function which returns the number of nodes in a binary tree.

In my view, an empty binary tree has a root which points to nullptr in C++, so there technically is one node or zero nodes.

I would appreciate it if someone could possibly make it clear.

Comment: What if there is only one value ? Then it would not be pointing to null and its different scenario.

Comment: empty? does the binary tree exists on paper or not? if it exits it has one node, root. if it doesn't it has no nodes.

Comment: Thats not a very clear question. Each item in a tree is a node. So the number of items in your tree is the number of nodes you have. If you are asking how many root nodes there are in a binary tree, then that would be 1 node. If you are asking how many there are without counting, you would have to create a formula that is based on the height of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

> The number of nodes n in a full binary tree, is at least n = 2h+1 and at most n = 2^(h+1)-1, where h is the height of the tree. A tree consisting of only a root node has a height of 0.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees)

Therefore, your first answer is indeed correct. An **initialized empty** binary tree would have only 1 node, however 0 in height.